# How to show as editable text in Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am using the below code to show data in table but it shows data as simple text but I want to make data in each cell editable so that I can edit each cell when I click over it. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
 <data-table
           :data="students"
    </data-table>
    <script>
    
    export default {
        name: "Test",
        data: () => ({
            students: [],
            }),
    
            methods: {
             getStudents (loading, page = 1, filter = '', sort = '', perPage = '') {
    
    
            axios.get('/api/students')
                    .then(function (response) {
                this.students = response.data.data;
    
            }
            }
    
            }
    }
    
    </script>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp ?

Comment: How it will work in vue JS. Could you please explain?

Comment: I also want to save editable value.

Comment: Does your API supports a POST to update the collection? What did you tried regarding this subject?

Comment: First, I want to make this editable when clicked and want to get the edited value and then will post using api.

Comment: Requires quite some code and can be made in various ways. What did you tried so far?